# navbar dropdown selected item text valve to pass to a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to pass the text valve from a navbar dropdown selection to a function.
The navbar dropdown list is created dynamically from a database.

When using $('#test').on('hide.bs.dropdown',...... I get the whole text from the dropdown and not the list item. if I add a after #test, nothing happens.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BMRA Data</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="test">
            <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Fuel Charts
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="fuellist">
                      <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>


$.ajax({
   url:  "getFuelList.php",
   dataType: 'json' 
  }).done(function (listData) {

  var list = document.getElementById("fuellist"); 

  listData.forEach(function (Id) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var text = document.createTextNode(Id.Id);

    link.appendChild(text);
    link.href = "#";
    li.appendChild(link);
    list.appendChild(li);
    });
})
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `var data = JSON.parse(listData)` ? Just before you do the foreach, so you do the `data.forEach` instead.

Comment: AFAIK: Sicne the `dataType` has been set so it is not necessary.